# Launch Java Application on Server using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat

I have to maintain and made some changes to an old java application.
It is a web application but the developers made it as simple java application not dynamic java web project.
Now, i am able to launch the application if i make a zipped file and deploy it in Tomcat Server.
But i want to launch appliocation from eclipse as I want to debug the application.
I am able to launch server from eclipse but when i open the aplication URL it shows:

```
localhost refused to connect.
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I am making following changes in my Run Configurations>Arguments:
Program Arguments:

> start

VM Arguments:

> Dcatalina.base="C:\Users\Sneezy\c\apache-tomcat-8.0.32"
>   Dcatalina.home="C:\Users\Sneezy\c\apache-tomcat-8.0.32"
>   Dwtp.deploy="C:\Users\Sneezy\c\apache-tomcat-8.0.32\wtpwebapps"
>   Djava.endorsed.dirs="C:\Users\Sneezy\c\apache-tomcat-8.0.32\endorsed"

I cannot the project faucets to dynamic web application as it introduces lots of errors in my application.
Are there are more changes i have to make?

Comment: Exactly what errors do you get when you're converting the project to a Dynamic Web Project?

Comment: Also, ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED suggests that there's no server running.

Comment: Okie .. There are project specific errors .